# Java Thread Pool - Using same thread to execute similar tasks

Tags: java, multithreading, threadpool, threadpoolexecutor, java-threads

I am looking for a way to have a java thread pool in which runnable tasks with same id should be processed by the same thread always.

Any help in this regard is greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Any details on why you want to do this and what you have tried will be greatly appreciated as well.

Comment: Based on your very generic description, you'd probably have to write this. If you can be more specific to what problem you're trying to solve that led to this idea, there might be a better solution that can be more easily done.

Comment: Hey @Chris sorry for such a generic question I will try to make it more specific I just got this question asked by a colleague and couldn't think of any possible solution for it hence the post, basically what I'm thinking of is whether can we have a job affinity that means suppose I submit job with some job id the job id should determine the thread which executes it something like `submit(Job id, Runnable job)` to the thread pool

Comment: I assume the goal is to take advantage of ThreadLocal cache or make sure that you never have more than one thread running a specific JobId at once (or perhaps something else)? These are both things that can be solved in other ways (respectively: shared cache, locks) that don't require complexity of matching jobs to certain threads.

Comment: People who are asking why would someone need this feature, let me explain with an example. Suppose we have a list of objects belonging to different groups. Now to process this list I would like a group to be always processed by the same thread, because I want the objects inside same group to be processed in sequence.